# How to set edittext on tableview on android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, tableview

I am using this tableview plugin https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView

What I am trying to do is to make the second column an input edittext, any help or suggestion would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to give a detailed answer as you give no code of what you are trying to do or how you have implemented using TableView.

The answer is based on the Sample App that is in Java as I have nothing else to go on, so you will have to convert to kotlin.

The first part if create a new layout to layout a cell with an edittext, I copied the `table_view_cell_layout.xml` in the sample App and called it `table_view_edit_layout.xml` and change the `TextView` widget to and `EditText` and set a few more options.
Full file below:-

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cell_container"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/cell_height"
              android:background="@color/cell_background_color"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cell_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/table_view_default_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        tools:text="Cell Data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Next is to create a ViewHolder for this layout, again copy the `CellViewHolder.java` file as `EditViewHolder.java` with some adjustments (see comments on where you should probably do more stuff).
Full file below:-

```java
package com.evrencoskun.tableviewsample.tableview.holder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.evrencoskun.tableview.adapter.recyclerview.holder.AbstractViewHolder;
import com.evrencoskun.tableviewsample.R;
import com.evrencoskun.tableviewsample.tableview.model.Cell;

import java.util.Locale;

public class EditViewHolder extends AbstractViewHolder {
    @NonNull
    private final EditText cell_edittext;
    @NonNull
    private final LinearLayout cell_container;

    private Cell cell;

    public EditViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cell_edittext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cell_data);
        cell_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cell_container);

        // Probably want to cover handling more ways of finishing editing than just Action Done / Enter
        cell_edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
                switch(result) {
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                    case EditorInfo.IME_NULL:
                        // Save the data to the model so it will be saved.
                        Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Cell " + cell.getId() + " new text= " + cell_edittext.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Probably make it not have have focus and hide the keyboard
                        cell_edittext.clearFocus();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cell_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCell(@Nullable Cell cell) {
        // Store Cell for later reference
        this.cell = cell;
        cell_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(cell.getData()));

        // If your TableView should have auto resize for cells & columns.
        // Then you should consider the below lines. Otherwise, you can ignore them.

        // It is necessary to remeasure itself.
        cell_container.getLayoutParams().width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        cell_edittext.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

**NOTE this does not handle saving the change text to what ever data model you are using, it just display the changed text in a `Toast`, So the data will be lost if you scroll the item off the screen.**

The final part is adjust the TableViewAdapter file to use the new `EditViewHolder`, much like the Adapter in the example App you just need to add new `switch` items much like `MOOD_CELL_TYPE` and `GENDER_CELL_TYPE`

add the View Type static at the top of the Adapter Class

```java
private static final int EDIT_CELL_TYPE = 3;
```

e.g. in `onCreateCellViewHolder` add the case

```java
            case EDIT_CELL_TYPE:
                // Get edittext cell layout which has EditText instead of TextView.
                layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_view_edit_layout, parent, false);

                return new EditViewHolder(layout);
```

in `onBindCellViewHolder` add the case

```java
case EDIT_CELL_TYPE:
                // Get the holder to update cell item text
                EditViewHolder editViewHolder = (EditViewHolder) holder;
                editViewHolder.setCell(cellItemModel);
                break;
```

in `getCellItemViewType` set column `2` to be `EDIT_CELL_TYPE` by adding the case

```java
           case 2:
                return EDIT_CELL_TYPE;
```

Hopefully this will give you the idea on how to add new cell types

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will check it out